# Sequelize setting MySQL auto-increment id to null

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

The crux of the problem is Sequelize is setting the id of my insert object to null. I've read a bunch of related problems and for the life of me I can't seem to figure it out.

Here's the schema for the MySQL 5.7 table

```sql
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `client_id` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `ipaddress` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `enabled` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `createdAt` datetime DEFAULT NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `updatedAt` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `roles` json DEFAULT NULL,
  `provider` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `users_id_uindex` (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `table_nameusers_username_uindex` (`username`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Here is Sequelize model, note I have primaryKey: true and autoIncrement: true

```
module.exports = function (sequelize, DataTypes) {
  return sequelize.define('User',
    {
      id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true,
      },
      username: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
      },
      password: DataTypes.STRING,
      client_id: DataTypes.STRING,
      ipaddress: DataTypes.STRING,
      enabled: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
      roles: [],
      provider: DataTypes.STRING,
    });
};
```

This is the error thrown when you try and insert again. Note the id: null

```
{
    "type": "error",
    "message": "PRIMARY must be unique",
    "error": {
        "name": "SequelizeUniqueConstraintError",
        "errors": [
            {
                "message": "PRIMARY must be unique",
                "type": "unique violation",
                "path": "PRIMARY",
                "value": "0",
                "origin": "DB",
                "instance": {
                    "id": null,
                    "username": "testuser",
                    "password": "<password string>",
                    "roles": [
                        "user",
                        "mysql"
                    ],
                    "provider": "SOMETHING",
                    "client_id": "",
                    "enabled": true,
                    "updatedAt": "2019-04-12T15:08:44.068Z",
                    "createdAt": "2019-04-12T15:08:44.068Z"
                },
                "validatorKey": "not_unique",
                "validatorName": null,
                "validatorArgs": []
            }
        ],
        "fields": {
            "PRIMARY": "0"
        },
        "parent": {
            "code": "ER_DUP_ENTRY",
            "errno": 1062,
            "sqlState": "23000",
            "sqlMessage": "Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'",
            "sql": "INSERT INTO `Users` (`id`,`username`,`password`,`client_id`,`enabled`,`roles`,`provider`,`createdAt`,`updatedAt`) VALUES (DEFAULT,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?);"
        },
        "original": {
            "code": "ER_DUP_ENTRY",
            "errno": 1062,
            "sqlState": "23000",
            "sqlMessage": "Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'",
            "sql": "INSERT INTO `Users` (`id`,`username`,`password`,`client_id`,`enabled`,`roles`,`provider`,`createdAt`,`updatedAt`) VALUES (DEFAULT,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?);"
        },
        "sql": "INSERT INTO `Users` (`id`,`username`,`password`,`client_id`,`enabled`,`roles`,`provider`,`createdAt`,`updatedAt`) VALUES (DEFAULT,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?);"
    }
}
```

Expected results: the id field to be the next auto-increment id.

Actual results: the id field is always 0 in the database and null in the Sequelize object.

Incidentally, I have ran this by manually creating the table and allowing Sequelize to create the table during sync().

Comment: `the id field to be the next auto-increment id` - you can never obtain this information. You can only insert and ask MySQL what the `auto_increment` it generated was.

Comment: @Mjh I understand that. However, when the record is inserted I can look at the database and see that the id wasn't set. I have also confirmed this on two separate node apps using Sequelize. However, if I perform an insert using just the mysql driver the id is created correctly.

Comment: I completely misunderstood your intent, sorry. What happens if you omit the definition of `id` from your sequelize model?

Comment: @Mjh same thing

Comment: Do you actually are setting the `id` as `null` on the object that you want to create? If that's the case then that's your problem. `null` or `0` are valid values, so when creating the record on the db will give you that error. You either don't set that attribute or `delete object.id`

Comment: @Ellebkey  values removed for brevity. This is the object being passed to Sequelize { username: '',
  password:'',
  roles:,
  provider: '',
  client_id:'',
  enabled: true,
  createdDate: '' 
} there is no id

Comment: What does your User.create() statement look like?  It should not include the `id` field, e.g.    `User.create({                                    
       username: 'testuser',
       password: 'testpwd',
       ... whatever ...
    });`

Comment: Only is you manually want to put the id, but does not make sense if you have `AUTO_INCREMENT`. Just not include the `id` field.

Comment: You need to include the Model.create() - that's where the bug is. Your table create sql indicates that there are already values in the table: `AUTO_INCREMENT=4`

Comment: @doublesharp  the Auto_Increment on the table create should be 1, I forgot to change it before pasting. There is no model create, there is the sequelize model which is posted. The post data which is a username, password json object is simply passed thru the controller to a service that does nothing but call a sequelize save() function. I'm starting to think the issue is in sequelize itself.

Comment: @RustedBucket model.create is the insert statement... point being you have a conflict on your primary key. you *do* have content in there or you wouldn't get the error.

Comment: @doublesharp table is empty/truncated. First record goes in with an auto-increment id of 0 the second record throws an error. I'm pretty confident this is a Sequelize issue.

Comment: Suit yourself - if you don't provide more info no one can help you. I highly doubt this is an issue with Sequelize.

Comment: I appreciate the attempt. I've given you everything there is. The error clearly shows what Sequelize is creating. I've set the documented parameters.